# Deleted File Still Shows (Sometimes) And I Checked Everywhere

Tags: files, filesystem, azure

I have a large (3.7GB) file that I deleted from my Ubuntu VM running in the Azure cloud. I first noticed a problem because the space from the file was not reclaimed. When I do an `ls` there is no sign of the file. However, if I execute `locate` for the filename then it returns the path of the file that was deleted.

If you try and edit the file there is nothing there.  If you use `du` it returns that there is no file to give you the size of.

I have used `lsof` to try and find any processes using the file as well as this command I found - `sudo find /proc/*/fd -ls | grep  '(deleted)'`.

I restarted the VM and this did not make a difference.

This machine has been running for a couple of years and we have never had this problem with it before.

Any help anyone can give me is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: please run `updatedb` to update your locate database.

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen - sorry I did not think of that for the locate command but the space still appears to be taken up by the file.